# Question regarding Big - O

Tags: analysis, functions, discrete-mathematics

If $f(x)$ is $O(g(x))$, then does it follow that $ 2^{f(x)} $ is $ O(2^{g(x)}) $

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Specifically, $2x$ is $O(x)$, but $2^{2x} = 4^x$ eventually outgrows $c\cdot 2^x$ for any real number $c$.